# Multiplying out squared brackets

Tags: exponentiation, education, simple-functions

This seems like a very simple problem, but I am getting confused.

When you multiply out say $(x+4)^2$ then it is the same as $x(x + 4) + 4(x + 4)$, so I believe the correct output would be $x^2 + 8x + 16$

However, on a video I am following there is the equation $3(x-1)^2 - 5$, where $x = 3$.

In the video they simply work out by doing:

= $3(3-1)^2 - 5$

= $3(2)^2 - 5$

= $3(4) - 5$

= $7$

I am confused why this equation doesn't follow the same formula as used in the $(x + 4)^2$ example. i.e. why doesn't it work to do $3(x(x - 1) - 1(x - 1)) - 5$ which would be:

= $3(x(x - 1) - 1(x - 1)) - 5$

= $3(x^2 -2x + 2) - 5$

= $3x^2 - 6x + 6 - 5$

= $3(3)^2 - 6(3) + 1$

= $27 - 18 + 1$

= $10$

I realize this is probably very very basic, but it is still confusing to me, so I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: You have a mistake in expanding the brackets of $(x-1)^2$. It should be $(x-1)(x-1)=x(x-1)-1\cdot(x-1)=x^2-x-x+1=x^2-2x+1$, insted of your $x^2-2x+2$

Comment: I think you made a mistake. I assume you wanted $x^2-2x+1$ instead of $x^2-2x+2$. Then everything matches.

Comment: You CAN do it both ways, but you have made a mistake in your expansion in the second example. Can you find out where?

Comment: That is embarrassing. Thank you all!

Comment: Well as they say, _to err is human_. Don't get disheartened. Everyone faces   something like this.

Comment: It’s less work to substitute for $x$ first.